# Merge..USING..WHEN SQL Server equivalent in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql-server, postgresql

Right now, we are trying to migrate a stored procedure from SQL Server to PostgreSQL. In this, We saw a querying method `MERGE..USING..WHEN`. So I couldn't find the equivalent. So is there any option to replicate this functionality? The actual query is given below.

```
WITH phase_list AS (
    SELECT @id_plant AS id_plant
         , id_phase
         , date_started
    FROM OPENJSON(@phase_list)
                  WITH (
                      id_phase INT '$.id_phase',
                      date_started DATE '$.date_started'
                      )
    WHERE date_started IS NOT NULL
    )
    MERGE grow.plant_phase AS t
USING phase_list AS s
ON s.id_plant = t.id_plant AND s.id_phase = t.id_phase
WHEN MATCHED AND (t.date_started <> s.date_started) THEN
    UPDATE
    SET t.date_started=s.date_started,
        t.date_updated=getutcdate(),
        t.updated_by=@id_user
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    INSERT (id_plant, id_phase, date_started, created_by, updated_by)
    VALUES (s.id_plant, s.id_phase, s.date_started, @id_user, @id_user)
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE AND t.id_plant = @id_plant THEN
    DELETE;
```

Can we replicate the same using any join operation with some if/else conditions? or any other approach?

Comment: Except for the `DELETE` part, you can use `insert ... on conflict () do update` assuming you have a unique constraint

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I update the code. right now, Am using `WITH...as... INSERT INTO...SELECT...    FROM phase_list s LEFT JOIN grow.plant_phase AS t ON s.id_plant = t.id_plant AND s.id_phase = t.id_phase...    ON CONFLICT (id_plant) DO UPDATE SET t.date_started=s.date_started, t.date_updated= now() at time zone 'utc', t.updated_by=_id_user; ` Problem is, `ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "s"` where `s.date_started`. So the update query is not able to get the from clause from above statement.